# Split ObservableCollection into limited amount collection

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I'm working on a payment report printer for work and have an ObservableCollection that fills when the client's name is selected. So, for example, I have a collection name Clients which can have up to only 60 entries. For printing purposes, I need to separate this into 5 separate lists and I can't think of how to go about it.

This is the class for the items used if helps any

```
public class payment
{
    public string amount { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Dose this answer your question? [how to split ObservableCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937948/how-to-split-observablecollection)

Comment: Can you not just create an `List<ObservableCollection<payment>>`, and then populate it with smaller `ObservableCollection<payment>` collections in a loop? What have you tried so far, where specifically are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a collection name Clients which can have up to only 60 entries. For printing purposes, I need to separate this into 5 separate lists

I guess this might look something like:

```
// An observable collection of 60 items
var clients = new ObservableCollection<Payment>(
    Enumerable.Range(0, 60).Select(i => new Payment {Amount = i.ToString()}));

// The number of lists to create
var numLists = 5;
var itemsPerList = clients.Count / numLists + 1;

// Create a list of new ObservableCollections
var smallerCollections = new List<ObservableCollection<Payment>>();

// Copy the items from 'clients' into smaller collections of
// 'itemsPerList' size, and add those to the smallerCollections list
for (var i = 0; i < clients.Count; i++)
{
    // Add a new list every time we add 'itemsPerList' items
    if (i % itemsPerList == 0) smallerCollections.Add(new ObservableCollection<Payment>());

    // Add this item to the last list
    smallerCollections.Last().Add(clients[i]);
}
```